# Raspbian GrovePi Python Error "Too many values to unpack"

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, grovepi+

We're currently working on a temperature/humidity sensor on a Raspberry Pi 3 B. The DHT22 sensor is pluged in on a GrovePi. The sensor is working fine so far.

Let's come to the actual problem:

```
    import grovepi

# Connect the Grove Temperature & Humidity Sensor Pro to digital port D4
# SIG,NC,VCC,GND
sensor = 4

while True:
    try:
        [temp,humidity] = grovepi.dht(sensor,1)
        print "temp =", temp, " humidity =", humidity

    except IOError:
        print "Error"
```

This is our Python Script. It should print out temperature and humidity. But when we execute the script we receive the following exception:

**[temp.humidity] = grovepi.dht(sensor, 1)**

**ValueError: too many values to unpack**

You can see the script and expected outcome at this website:

http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Temperature_and_Humidity_Sensor_Pro/

Comment: Your snippet contains correct `[temp,humidity]` phrase, yet your error message contains `[temp.humidity]`; check your code for a typo.

Comment: Please check [temp.humidity].   The code should be [temp, humidity].

Comment: Run the script using `out=grovepi.dht(sensor,1)` and after `print(out, type(out))`

Comment: Thank you guys, you helped me alot. Were currently fighting with the issue that it gives out only -1 as temperature :(